# Mod_rewrite uses only some rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tuote\.php/([^/]+) tuote.php?data=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ryhma\.php/([^/]+) ryhma.php?data=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ostoskori ostoskori.php [L]
RewriteRule ^lisaa\/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=4&data=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^lisaa-ostoskoriin/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=1&data=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule tyhjenna-ostoskori ostoskori.php?a=2

RewriteRule ^vahenna\/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=3&data=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^poista\/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=5&data=$1 [L,NC]
```

When I access `lisaa-ostoskoriin`, it doesn´t work and seems to connect `ostoskori.php` but it should connect `ostoskori.php?a=1&data=$1`.

When I access `tyhjenna-ostoskori`, it doesn´t either work and seems to connect `ostoskori.php` but it should `ostoskori.php?a=2`.

All others will work, but these are only that do not work. How should I modify the code to make it work better?

**URL examples**
http://somesite.com/tuote/1-Product-name --> `tuote.php?data=1-Product-name`
http://somesite.com/ryhma/1-Category-name --> `ryhma.php?data=1-Category-name`
http://somesite.com/ostoskori --> `ostoskori.php`
http://somesite.com/lisaa/1-Product-name --> `ostoskori.php?a=4&data=1-Product-name`
http://somesite.com/lisaa-ostoskoriin/1-Product-name --> `ostoskori.php?a=1&data=1-Product-name`

Comment: It would be good to have some example urls to work with. Should your rules apply to the url base eg. ^/lisaa/?

Comment: @unNamed I added some examples, look if they are better now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(tuote|ryhma)\.php/([^/]+) $1.php?data=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^/lisaa-ostoskoriin/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=1&data=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/tyhjenna-ostoskori ostoskori.php?a=2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/vahenna/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=3&data=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/lisaa/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=4&data=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/poista/([^/]+) ostoskori.php?a=5&data=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^/ostoskori ostoskori.php [L]
```

I haven't tested it myself tho. But the order and the regex is quite important here, since each following match results in a substituion.

Comment: Thank you. It helped. But I had to take off the `/` before rules.